# Apache2 vHost conf - redirect to different server

Tags: redirect, apache2, port, virtualhost

**the situation**

Server 1: Apache2 serving regular websites from port 80

Server 2: Runs dedicated JAVA website application served from port 8080 (application default)

Using off-site DNS service to direct all port 80 requests for my domain names to my external IP. Server 1 uses several vHost config files to direct to Apache2 html folders so users see correct websites.

**the problem**

Directing 1 domain name to Server 2 via Server 1 Apache2 vHost config files without using internal DNS server.

**the example**

Server 1 vHost config file for default website:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.mdom.com
ServerAlias www.mdom.com

DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public_html

<Directory /var/www/html/public_html>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_auth_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.mdom.com-access.log "Combined"
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.mdom.com-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Server 1 vHost config file for directing to Server 2 application:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName app.mdom.com
ServerAlias app.mdom.com

DocumentRoot //server2:8080

<Directory //server2:8080>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_auth_core.c>
        Require all granted
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/app.mdom.com-access.log "Combined"
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/app.mdom.com-error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

**notice `//server2` in the 2nd file**

But somehow this doesn't really work. It shows "Forbidden", "you don't have permission to access / on this server".

Keep in mind there is no apache2 installed on Server 2, the JAVA website works when calling Server 2 via port 8080 using either internal IP or external domain name, as long as I use port 8080 in the url.

**the question**

Is it possible to instruct Server 1's apache2 to redirect `app.mdom.com` to Server 2 port 8080?

***TL:DR?*** I'm trying to be thorough and provide as much information as possible

Answer (score 5):

I've read through the documentation of the application and somewhere hidden between several pages of code there was a small paragraph of how to setup a proxy with Apache2 to route requests for that subdomain to Server 2.

**example**

Put this in the Apache2 vHost config file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app.mdom.com
    ProxyPass /app http://server2:8080/app
    ProxyPassReverse /app http://server2:8080/app
</VirtualHost>
```

... and activate the host:

```
a2ensite app.mdom.com.conf
```

... then reconfigure Apache2 to process proxy:

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
```

Tested and works.